# Loop through an array of objects using forEach

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, ecmascript-6, foreach

Having the following input:

```
const myArray = [{data: {value: 1, name: 'john', age: 22 } },{data: {value: 2, name: 'mike', age: 42 } }];
```

It is wanted to loop through this array in order to create a new one containing only some of the data, in this case name and age.

The result should be: `[{name: 'john', age: 22 }, {name: 'mike', age: 42 }]`

I've tried to use forEach:

```
const result = myArray.forEach(el => ({el.data.name, el.data.age}));
```

What is wrong with this solution?

Comment: `forEach` doesn't return anything (explicitly).

Comment: Just replace `forEach` with `map` and you're done

Comment: @CristianTraìna also `el => ({el.data.name, el.data.age}))` -> `el => ({name: el.data.name, age: el.data.age})` or `({data: {name, age}}) => ({name, age})`

Comment: [`Array.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach): _"Return value: `undefined`."_

Comment: @VLAZ I hadn't noticed it, good catch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `Array#forEach()` method does not return a value, we do not assign it to a variable but rather use it as we would a loop:

```js
const myArray = [{data: {value: 1, name: 'john', age: 22 } },{data: {value: 2, name: 'mike', age: 42 } }];

const result = [];
myArray.forEach( ({data: {name,age}}) => result.push( {name,age} ) );

console.log( result );
```

**OR**:

```js
const myArray = [{data: {value: 1, name: 'john', age: 22 } },{data: {value: 2, name: 'mike', age: 42 } }];

const result = [];
myArray.forEach( ({data: {value, ...desired}}) => result.push( desired ) );

console.log( result );
```